# active required validation on radio button selection

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

i want to active / disable required field on dropdownlist , if radiobutton1 checked requiredvalidator active else remain disable.

html code

```
 <asp:RadioButton runat="server" id="radioA1" GroupName="overseas" /> 
  <label for="radioA1">Yes </label> 

  <asp:RadioButton runat="server" id="radioA2" GroupName="overseas" /> 
  <label for="radioA2">No</label>

  <asp:RadioButton runat="server" id="radioA3" GroupName="overseas" /> 
  <label for="radioA2">Not Applicable</label>
  <br />
  Overseas Country 
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList10" AppendDataBoundItems="True" CssClass="form-control mySelecBox" runat="server" DataSourceID="newCountry" DataTextField="Country" DataValueField="CountryGuid">
          <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" />                              
  </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="newCountry" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:umtonlineConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [CountryGuid], [Country] FROM [countries]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator13" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownList10" Enabled="False" ErrorMessage="Oversea country required *" ForeColor="#CC0000" ValidationGroup="step1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                        <br />
```

Jquery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#<%=radioA1.ClientID%>').click(function () {

            alert("its working");     // this part work fine.

            ValidatorEnable($('#<%=RequiredFieldValidator13%>'));

        });
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

First, that should obviously be calling ClientID:

```
'#<%=RequiredFieldValidator13.ClientID%>'
```

Second, ValidatorEnable expects a dom object, not a jQuery one. So

```
var validator = document.getElementById('<%=RequiredFieldValidator13.ClientID%>');
```

or, as suggested by kman in the comments:

```
var validator = $('#<%=RequiredFieldValidator13.ClientID%>')[0];
```

Third, it also expects a second parameter, boolean specifying whether to enable or disable the validator. I guess this should be set according to the dropdownlist value.

Comment: Just wanted to comment that you can use jQuery for selecting your element, you'd just have to unwrap it to expose the DOM object. Just index into it to unwrap. $('#<%=RequiredFieldValidator13.ClientID%>')[0]